# Where to find the Kubernetes Scheduler Configuration file in local system

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am currently working in Minikube cluster and looking to change some flags of kubernetes scheduler configuration, but I can't find it. The file looks something like-

```
apiVersion: kubescheduler.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: KubeSchedulerConfiguration
algorithmSource:
  provider: DefaultProvider
...
disablePreemption: true
```

What is it's name and where can I find it?

Comment: I'd reckon you could check the `/etc/kubernetes` and `/etc/kubernetes/manifests` directories within your `minikube` instance. You can connect to it by `$ minikube ssh`. Have you checked those directories? Also you can pass some scheduler configuration options by `minikube start --extra-config=scheduler....`: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/config/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this answer as a community wiki to set a baseline and to provide additional resources/references rather than giving a definitive solution.

Feel free to edit and expand.

---

I haven't found the file that you are referencing (`KubeSchedulerConfiguration`) in `minikube`.

The `minikube` provisioning process does not create it nor references it in the configuration files (`/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml` and the `--config=PATH` parameter).

I'd reckon you could take a look on other Kubernetes solutions where you can configure how your cluster is created (how `kube-scheduler` is configured). Some of the options are:

- [Kubernetes.io: Docs: Setup: Production environment: Tools: Kubeadm: Create cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/) and also:

  - *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Setup: Production environment: Tools: Kubeadm: Control plane flags](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/control-plane-flags/)*
- *[Github.com: Kubernetes sigs: Kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray)*

> A side note!
>
> Both: `kubespray` and `minikube` are using `kubeadm` as a bootstrapper!

I would also consider creating additional scheduler that would be responsible for spawning your workload (by referencing in the `YAML` manifests):

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Tasks: Extend Kubernetes: Configure multiple schedulers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/configure-multiple-schedulers/)*

---

I haven't tested it extensively and in the long term but I've managed to include the `YAML` manifest that you are referencing for the `kube-scheduler`.

> **Disclaimers!**
>
> 1. Please consider below example as a **workaround**!
> 2. The method described below is not persistent.

Steps:

- Start your `minikube` instance with the `--extra-config`
- Connect to your `minikube` instance and edit/add files:

  - `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml`
  - newly created `KubeSchedulerConfiguration`
- Delete the failing `kube-scheduler` `Pod` and wait for it to be recreated.

#### Start your `minikube` instance with the `--extra-config`

As previously said you can add some additional parameters for your `$ minikube start` to be passed down to the provisioning process.

In this setup you can either pass it with `$ minikube start ...` or do it manually later on.

- `$ minikube start --extra-config=scheduler.config="/etc/kubernetes/sched.yaml"`

Above parameter will add the `- --config=/etc/kubernetes/sched.yaml` to the `command` of your `kube-scheduler`. It will look for the file in the mentioned location.

#### Connect to your `minikube` instance (`$ minikube ssh`) and edit/add files:

Your `kube-scheduler` will fail as you've passed an argument (`config`) that is incorrect (lack of file). To work around this you will need to:

- add: `/etc/kubernetes/sched.yaml` with your desired configuration
- modify: `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml`:

1. add to: `volumeMounts`:

```yaml
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/sched.yaml
      name: scheduler
      readOnly: true
```

2. add to `volumes`:

```yaml
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/sched.conf
      type: FileOrCreate
    name: scheduler
```

#### Delete the failing `kube-scheduler` `Pod` and wait for it to be recreated.

You will need to redeploy modified scheduler to get its new config running:

- `$ kubectl delete pod -n kube-system kube-scheduler-minikube`

After some time you should see your `kube-scheduler` in `Ready` state.

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Scheduling eviction: Kube-scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/kube-scheduler/)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Reference: Command line tools reference: Kube-scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-scheduler/)*